# Check if each row of a data frame is contained in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I wrote the following function, it works. However it is very slow when `df1` has 1700 rows, and `df2` has 70000 rows. Is there anyway to improve the efficiency?

```
rowcheck <- function(df1, df2){
         apply(df1, 1, function(x) any(apply(df2, 1, function(y) all(y==x))))
}
```

An example I wrote this function to apply to is: I want to check whether each row in df1 is contained as a row in df2:

```
df1=data.frame(a=c(1:3),b=c("a","b","c"))
df2=data.frame(a=c(1:6),b=rep(c("a","b","c"),2))
```

For each row of df1, I want to check if it is contained as a row in df2. I want to return of the function to be a logical vector of length nrow(df1).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `all(y %in% x)`? I suggest you provide a simple example that demonstrates your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The **dplyr** package has a `setdiff` method for data.frame's that you might investigate.

Comment: otherwise i would paste values line per line with u <- do.call(paste, df1) and v <- do.call(paste, df2) and then do u%in%v, but i don't check the computation time

Comment: @droopy u%in%v work great for one dimentional u, and a vector v where each element is also one dimentional. However, when u is a vector, say u=(x1,x2), and v is a matrix or data frame of m x 2 dimention, the %in% does not work correctly. Am I missing something with %in%？

Comment: yes because my solution is exactly the one that Richard copy and paste into a function

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way is to paste the rows together, and compare them with `%in%`.  The result is a logical vector the length of `nrow(df1)`, as requested.

```
do.call(paste0, df1) %in% do.call(paste0, df2)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. So basically you are reducing the column dimension to 1 so you could use %in%. So I guess %in% only works for one dimentional variable check.

Comment: This is such a perfect and clean solution to my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Filter(function(x) x > 0, which(duplicated(rbind(df2, df1))) - nrow(df2))
```

It will tell you which row numbers in `df1` occur in `df2`. If you want an atomic vector of logicals like in Richard Scriven's answer, try

```
duplicated(rbind(df2, df1))[-seq_len(nrow(df2))]
```

It is also faster since it uses an internal C function `duplicated` (mine is `rowcheck2`)

```
> microbenchmark(rowcheck(df1, df2), rowcheck2(df1, df2))
 Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
  rowcheck(df1, df2) 2.045210 2.169182 2.328296 3.539328 13.971517   100
  rowcheck2(df1, df2) 1.046207 1.112395 1.243390 1.727921  7.442499   100
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, will this not fail if there are duplicate values in `df1`? The OP does not seems to make any indication that `df1` will not have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give my two cents on this query. A plyr-based solution:

```
nrow(match_df(df2, df1))
```

.. Will check each row of df1 against df2 (with respect to all columns) and give you the number of rows of df1 contained in df2.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `merge` is:

```r
# simulate data
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
set.seed(1)
n1 <- 400L
n2 <- 1000L
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample.int(20L, n1, TRUE) ,
                  b = sample(letters, n1, TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(a = sample.int(20L, n2, TRUE),
                  b = sample(letters, n2, TRUE))
df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2), ]

# the new function
row_check_new <- function(x, y){
  # are there columns in x that are not in y or vice versa?
  if(length(union(colnames(x), colnames(y))) > length(colnames(x)))
    return(logical(NROW(x)))
  dum <- transform(x, row_id_dummy = 1:NROW(x))
  dum$row_id_dummy %in% merge(dum, y)$row_id_dummy
}

# it yields the same
rowcheck <- function(df1, df2)
  apply(df1, 1, function(x) any(apply(df2, 1, function(y) all(y==x))))

all.equal(rowcheck(df1, df2), row_check_new(df1, df2))
#R> [1] TRUE

# but is much faster
bench::mark(old = rowcheck(df1, df2), new = row_check_new(df1, df2))
#R> # A tibble: 2 x 13
#R>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#R>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#R> 1 old        322.56ms 327.26ms      3.06    11.4MB    18.3      2    12
#R> 2 new          1.25ms   1.31ms    736.     222.8KB     6.00   368     3
```

This works with duplicates in `df1`. The solution by [Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674231/5861244) is faster. There are some corner cases where the solution based on `merge` is preferable as Rich Scriven's solution will give an incorrect answer. For instance, consider the following example with integers

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = 11, x2 = 1)
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 11)

do.call(paste0, df1) %in% do.call(paste0, df2)
#R> [1] TRUE
rowcheck(df1, df2)
#R> [1] FALSE
row_check_new(df1, df2)
#R> [1] FALSE
```