# Coordinate matching matrix's in R

Tags: r, indexing, match

currently I have to matrixs, and I am trying to return the index values where they match in z?
This is what I have currently

```
           x y
matrixloc 0 0
          2 1
          2 3
          2 6
          5 5
          6 7
          4 9
> z
 x y
[1,] 2 6
[2,] 3 4
[3,] 5 5
[4,] 2 1
[5,] 2 3
[6,] 6 7  
[7,] 4 9
[8,] 6 8
```

currently the output I am getting is  :

```
     match(matrixloc,z)
  NA  1  1  1  3  6  7 NA 12  2  6  3 14 15
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: hoping to get:(NA,4,5,1,3,6,7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if each row of a data frame is contained in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673335/check-if-each-row-of-a-data-frame-is-contained-in-another-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one (of many) ways using `match` on the `paste`d column entries

```
# Your sample data
matrixloc <- as.matrix(read.table(text =
    "x y
     0 0
     2 1
     2 3
     2 6
     5 5
     6 7
     4 9", header = T));
z <- as.matrix(read.table(text =
    "x y
     2 6
     3 4
     5 5
     2 1
     2 3
     6 7
     4 9
     6 8", header = T));

match(apply(matrixloc, 1, paste, collapse = "_"), apply(z, 1, paste, collapse = "_"));
#[1] NA  4  5  1  3  6  7
```

Also, **the plural form of "matrix" is "matrices"**, not "matrixs".